# Android How to make unclickable other elements when fragment is showed [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I have ConstraintLayout. Inside it i have three elements: Toolbar, RecyclerView and FragmentContainerView in the center. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuOFo.png).

I made clickable RecyclerView and when I click on the selected item im adding new fragment on  FragmentContainerView

```
 adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object: RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
        override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentcontainer_id, Fragment1::class.java,null).addToBackStack(null).commit()
        }

    })
```

The problem is that after fragment is showed, I can still scroll RecyclerView and interact with it. I want to make all other elements unclickable until I close my opened fragment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add an `if` condition in your click listener to check if the fragment's already displayed, and basically do nothing if that's the case. If you include a tag when `add`ing the fragment, [you could just check if it's already added](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#finding):

```
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
    val tag = "my cool fragment"
    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentcontainer_id, Fragment1::class.java, null, tag) // tagged here
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    } // does nothing if a fragment with that tag already exists
}
```